# How to SSL/TLS with Springboot and java GRPC

Tags: spring-boot, grpc-java

I am working with Springboot and Grpc on the intercommunication between services. Things are working fine but now I want to use TLS for Grpc.
For this, I use the following properties on the server-side.

Now the problem here I am using facing is, the value of cert and key will come from Kubernetes. But configuration expecting it from the file. So what I want is that I will populate the value of these variables from Kubernetes as value, not as a file path.

```
grpc.security.cert-chain=${CRT}
grpc.security.private-key=${KEY}
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Please, can you provide wich grpc dependency you are using?

Comment: @Muhammad Arslan did you manage to figure it out?